# Failed to INSERT into database by passing variables with data from form using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, insert

I have this (soon-to-be, hopefully) ABM application running on XAMPP.
I've already dealt with its validations and the query for the insert.

I have a file for registering subjects, in an html form, with a button type="submit".

So, when the options are selected and the input filled, when pressing the button a function is called (in a javascript file) --> it validates the data and sends a request to put the info in a database. Here's the js file:

```
function registerSubjects(){
var carreraMateria = "";
var nombreMateria = "";
var descripcionMateria = "";
var cargaHorariaMateria = "";

if(validacionFormularioAlta()){  //this is the main validating function
        $.ajax({
                url:  'http://localhost/path/registerSubjects.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {"carreraMateria": carreraMateria, 
                       "nombreMateria": nombreMateria, 
                       "descripcionMateria": descripcionMateria,
                       "cargaHorariaMateria": cargaHorariaMateria,
                       },
                dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: function() {    
                    console.log("I'm in before send part");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if( data == "OK"){
                        console.log("it saved the data");
                        location.href = "http://localhost/path/main.php";
                        return;
                    }

                    //Note: There are better ways, this is just because I'm learning, will try to improve on it later :)
                    if( data == "ERROR"){    
                        console.log("not saved");
                        alert("error, please try again");
                        return;
                    }

                    alert("Server message: " + data);


                }

        });
    }else{
        alert("Incorrect inputs");
    }
}
```

Data from the form is "caught" using these variables (javascript file):

```
    carreraMateria = document.getElementById("carreraMateria").selectedIndex;
    nombreMateria = document.getElementById("nombreMateria").value;
    descripcionMateria = document.getElementById("descripcionMateria").value;
    cargaHorariaMateriaElemento = document.getElementById("cargaHorariaMateria");
    cargaHorariaMateriaSeleccion = document.getElementById("cargaHorariaMateria").selectedIndex;
    cargaHorariaMateria = parseInt(document.getElementById("cargaHorariaMateria").value);
```

And..... this is the registerSubjects.php which deals with some server-side validations and the INSERT:

```
<?php
//Connection data
include("../extras/conexion.php");

//Inicialization of variables
$carreraMateria = "";
$nombreMateria = "";
$descripcionMateria = "";
$cargaHorariaMateria = "";

//Getting data
$carreraMateria = $_POST['carreraMateria']; 
$nombreMateria = $_POST['nombreMateria']; 
$descripcionMateria = $_POST['descripcionMateria'];
$cargaHorariaMateria = $_POST['cargaHorariaMateria'];

//CONNECTION
$CONN = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $dataBase);

// Verifico la conexion
if ($CONN->connect_error) {
    die("Problema al conectar con la base de datos" . $CONN->connect_error);
    return;
} 

//INSERT!
//Query para introducir los datos en la base
$SQL = "INSERT INTO subjects(career_id, name, description, hours) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? )";

if($stmt = $CONN->prepare($SQL))
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $carreraMateria, $nombreMateria, $descripcionMateria, $cargaHorariaMateria);
    $stmt->execute();
    $id = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
}

//Check for row modification
if($id>0 ){
    echo "OK";
}else{
    echo "ERROR";
}

return;

?>
```

And so it is... I had the connection part and its checking in a different file, but was causing some problems. I've written that in the files themeselves and now the ajax is working "fine"... well, at least is working :/

The thing is... I can't insert anything... I'm stuck in my own alert, in the part that says (in the AJAX part):

```
if( data == "ERROR"){
    console.log("not saved");
    alert("error, please try again");
    return;
}
```

Can't seem to be realizing what's wrong. At first I wasn't "catching" the values in the JS file correctly, I've fixed that, but now I can't have the INSERT working right.

Apparently I'm getting the values right (from the form, from what was selected), and I'm referencing them well, so I'm pretty confused.

---

EDIT1:
I've tried getting the values received in the php file; I've done this:

```
$carreraMateria = $_POST['carreraMateria']; 
var_dump($_POST["carreraMateria"]);
$nombreMateria = $_POST['nombreMateria'];
var_dump($_POST["nombreMateria"]);
$descripcionMateria = $_POST['descripcionMateria'];
var_dump($_POST["descripcionMateria"]);
$cargaHorariaMateria = $_POST['cargaHorariaMateria'];
var_dump($_POST["cargaHorariaMateria"]);
```

And the result was:

```
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
```

Then I GUESS I'm not getting the data correctly...? :/

---

EDIT2:
I've disabled the PHP and AJAX parts, and was just testing the JavaScript. I've "caught" the values and printed them into console log, and they show fine, so now the problem is with transferring them into the PHP file to insert them into the database.

Comment: the error is in your php script, it retuns ERROR as String. the javascript works fine

Comment: There is too much irrelevant code here. You should try to cut down on the code and only post the most minimal and related lines. It makes debugging much easier. People are less interested in debugging 300 lines of code when they can not run it directly in their own environment.

Comment: a small tipp, don't let php echo ok or error. make it with `http_response_code(200)` and `http_response_code(400)` . than you can catch real errors with ajax and success and error function

Comment: @OptimusCrime ok, sorry, will try to cut it a bit. I just don't want to miss anything that perhaps it's important

Answer (score 0):

```
if($stmt = $CONN->prepare($SQL)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $carreraMateria, $nombreMateria, $descripcionMateria, $cargaHorariaMateria);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->execute();
    $id = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

there was a missing open bracked

Comment: Hi! Where? I can't seem to find it, to me it looks the same :/

Comment: your if only effects the first line because the bracket is missin

Comment: mm ok, I still see the brakets right.. my bad, I'm so lost. The only thing I see different is the  execiting part twice. Still, I've done it again and still doesn't insert :(

Comment: have you checked the php alone? print out your sql responses step for step

Comment: I thought of that, and tried but failed.. Will try to investigate a bit more with that and see what happens. I must be close, but can't get it right :/ Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is functioning now :)
In the javascript file, I had declared the variables meant for initialization inside the function registerSubjects(), and so they were empty when trying to pass them. They had to be declared as global variables, outside the function.